# Using VBScript, how can I run commands inside GitHub's 'Git Shell'?

Tags: git, vbscript

I have a very specific question. Details follow:
I do not have Git installed. 
I have only installed the GitHub desktop client (and the in-built Git it has).
By default, they create a "Git Shell" desktop icon which launches your preferred shell (Cmd, Powershell, etc.) with git commands enabled. I don't know how this magical shortcut works!
The problem is - I can invoke the shell by calling:

```
WshShell.Run("C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell", 1, True)
```

- same as that desktop shortcut, but the above command opens the new command prompt and moves on.

How can I execute commands in this newly launched window?

Comment: Simplest thing would be to either figure out where those commands are installed or to install Git for windows and add it to the path.

Comment: I am avoiding using Git for windows because GitHub's Git Shell doesn't ask for credentials. If I use Git for windows then I'll have to do password management. Plus I read somewhere that Git requires you to type in the password - which defeats the purpose of automation.

Comment: Git for Windows does have [Windows Credential Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) that does not require that, but you can also set up SSH as well. I would assume that GitHub's underlying Git client is doing one of those two things.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [crashmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1441/crashmstr) for his advice.

I installed Git for Windows. It asked for my Github credential only on the first execution of git clone. Now my VBS can open a normal command prompt and execute the git commands without prompting for credentials every-time.

---

This allows me to automate this particular solution but it leaves me wondering 'How can I execute commands on a command prompt window which was already open when my VBS execution began?'
But that's a different question altogether! :)

*Let's see if I can find a better solution than an unreliable approach to use AppActivate followed by SendKeys!*